# Python: Mutables in class states, what's going on under the hood?

Tags: python, class, oop, low-level

I'm currently doing an online course on OOP in Python and one of the skill tests was to write a password generator class. Below you'll find the recommended answer.

```
import re
import random
from string import ascii_letters, punctuation
from copy import copy

class Password:
    
    SAMPLES = {
        "letters": list(ascii_letters),
        "numbers": list(range(10)),
        "punctuation": list(punctuation)
    }
    
    DEFAULT_SETTINGS = {
        "low": 8,
        "mid": 12,
        "high": 16
    }
    
    @classmethod
    def show_input_universe(cls):
        return cls.SAMPLES
    
    
    def _generate_password(self):
        
        population = self.SAMPLES["letters"]
        length = self.length or self.DEFAULT_SETTINGS.get(self.strength)
        
        if self.strength == "high":
            population += self.SAMPLES["numbers"] + self.SAMPLES["punctuation"]
        elif self.strength == "mid":
            population += self.SAMPLES["numbers"]
        else:
            pass
        
        # map(lambda x: str(x), random...)
        self.password = "".join(map(str, random.choices(population, k=int(length))))
    
    
    def __init__(self, strength="mid", length=None): #None so there's no need for a value
        self.strength = strength
        self.length = length
        
        self._generate_password()
```

When using that code to create instances of that class and thus generate passwords that are either of high or mid security the underlying SAMPLES["letter] list is modified. That leads to low strength passwords sharing all the properties of the other password strenghts.

I could even see that effect when calling the show_input_universe method. The other lists were added to the original list.

But why is that?

I understand that `population = self.SAMPLES["letters"]` creates the population variable which stores a pointer to the self.SAMPLES["letters"] list.

But then how exactly does the concatenation work:

```
if self.strength == "high":
    population += self.SAMPLES["numbers"] + self.SAMPLES["punctuation"]
```

The solution to this is the following:

```
from copy import copy

population = Copy(self.SAMPLES["letters"])
```

As that creates a copy of the initial List that is only modified within the specific instances.

Comment: As a side note, this isn't a great example of OOP (and arguably a bad one - it's just a one-off function squished into a constructor). You could consider posting your code on [CodeReview.SE](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) so that they can rip it apart :)

Comment: This solution does not give me a good impression of the overall quality of the course. Aside from incorrectly mutating what should be a constant class value, the decision to leave `self.length` set to `None` until actually calling `self._generate_password` seems a bit odd. `__init__` itself could use `DEFAULT_SETTINGS`, and/or pass the desired length as an argument to `_generate_password`. It's also not clear that this should be a class at all, instead of a simple function.

Comment: Agreed on both points. I've seen this a lot unfortunately, and there seem to be many Python programming classes that teach really weird or outright bad techniques. As for OO specifically, a major "code smell" here is that all the work is performed in the `__init__` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of population is `list`.  List implements the datamodel hook [`__iadd__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=iadd#object.__iadd__) for in-place sequence concatenation. This method also returns the existing instance:

```
>>> population = [0, 1]
>>> new = population.__iadd__([2, 3])
>>> new is population
True
>>> population
[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

So, the augmented assignment statement `+=` mutates the original list, which is one of the values of the dict in the class namespace. It's in `Password.SAMPLES` - shared between all instances. **Even though `population` is a local variable inside your method, there is still shared state**.

Note that if list did not implement `__iadd__`, then your code would work as you expected because the augmented assigment would fall back to using `__add__`, concatenating and returning a new instance.  Replace `population += other` with `population = population + other` to see similar.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware that using augmented assignment operators is not the same as using just arithmetic operators. Great explanation!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```py
population = self.SAMPLES["letters"]
```

In Python, variables are *references* that point to a chunk of data*. A reference in this case is like a sticky note with a name written on it. You can attach several of them to the same chunk of data, and access that same chunk of data by any of the names of the variables that point to it. Assigning something to a different variable never** makes a copy.

Thus, the `population` variable is just a reference to the exact same list as `self.SAMPLES["letters"]`. So when you mutate `population`, you are *also* mutating `self.SAMPLES["letters"]`. This is why making a copy fixes the problem: because now they are two separate lists, so mutating one does not mutate the other.

As shown in the other answer, you can also make a copy of the list by invoking `list()` on it, or indexing with `[:]`. All of these are equivalent:

```py
population = list(self.SAMPLES["letters"])

population = self.SAMPLES["letters"][:]

from copy import copy
population = copy(self.SAMPLES["letters"])
```

*There are some exceptions in specific cases, but this is the correct mental model in general.

**Again, exceptions are possible, but none that are relevant here.

Comment: This doesn't really answer OP's question -- they already know that the variable is a reference, and they already know they can work around it by making a copy.  They were asking "how exactly does the concatenation work", which this doesn't address at all.

Comment: Appreciate the answer!

Answer (score -1):

The line:

```
population += self.SAMPLES["numbers"] + self.SAMPLES["punctuation"]
```

does not just rebind the `population` variable, it mutates the object that `population` currently references, which is `self.SAMPLES["letters"]`.  It's the same as doing:

```
population.extend(self.SAMPLES["numbers"] + self.SAMPLES["punctuation"])
```

or:

```
self.SAMPLES["letters"].extend(self.SAMPLES["numbers"] + self.SAMPLES["punctuation"])
```

Note that you don't need to import anything special to make a copy of a list; you can just use the `list` constructor to make a new list out of any iterable (including another list):

```
population = list(self.SAMPLES["letters"])
```

or you can use the built-in `list.copy` method:

```
population = self.SAMPLES["letters"].copy()
```

Comment: I think the key here is that `population` is a reference to the same list as `self.SAMPLES["letters"]self`, which IMO is a little obscured in this answer.

Comment: OP acknowledged that in their question, so it seems safe to assume that they understand it already: *I understand that population = self.SAMPLES["letters"] creates the population variable which stores a pointer to the self.SAMPLES["letters"] list.*

Comment: The line `population += ...` is _not_ the same as doing `population.extend(...)`. The latter wouldn't classify `population` as a local variable in the method at class definition time (because it's not an assignment statement), so the scoping rules of the code would be totally different. I've downvoted for this reason.

Comment: @wim `population` was already assigned as a local variable earlier in the same scope.  If it hadn't been, `+=` would produce a `NameError` rather than changing its scoping.  You can try running the different versions of the code yourself to see that they're equivalent.

Comment: Well, yes, that's exactly the difference in scoping rules that I'm talking about (by the way, it would be an `UnboundLocalError`, not a `NameError`). The equivalent is `population = population.__iadd__(other)`, not `population.extend(other)`, and even that is an approximation (because other might implement `__radd__`).